# Crash when launching ships in Industry Giant 2

Tags: technical-issues, industry-giant-2

I was recently asked about a crash that occurs **when launching ships** in Industry Giant 2. I have tried to reproduce it, but cannot. Has anyone else experienced this issue and if so is there a way to solve it? I suspect this issue may occur only for specific video cards.

For reference, [here is the comment thread pertaining to the issue on my website](http://www.thegameengine.org/industry-giant-2/industry-giant-2-windows-7/#comment-1051).

In order to avoid suggestions that have already been tried, here are the steps that I recommend when playing the game on Windows 7:

1. Install the IG2 addon version 2.1 patch OR disable popups and videos.
2. Install the video card fix.
3. Run installer.bat OR remove problem files
4. Run as administrator and with Windows 98 compatibility.

Comment: never happened to me, its not a good idea to force IG2 to crash. when it fails it fails bad :)